# For loop is not running once going inside an else that is further inside an else

Tags: c

I was trying to output First_Name when the user enters '0' and Last_Name when a '1' is entered and I did it with some other way first and was randomly changing the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    
    for (a = 0; a < 1 ; a--) {
        printf("ENTER 0 or 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
      
        if (a == 0) {  
            printf("First_Name");  
        } 
        else {  
            if (a == 1) {  
                printf("Last_Name\n");  
            } 
            else {  
                printf("Wrong Input. Please Try Again.\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I enter a '0' or a '1' the code is working as expected (it showed First_Name or Last_Name as desired) and then the prompt waited for the user to input again.

But once I entered any other number it just printed "Wrong Input. Please Try Again." and then exits.

Why?
(I am running the code on an online compiler.)

Comment: You're using the same variable to control the loop and accept input. If you enter a number other than 0 or 1 the loop will end because the condition is no longer true.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  (As well as reading [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/))  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: "randomly changing the code" is no way to code.  Why you would you do that "randomly".

Comment: The loop keeps repeating while `a < 1`, after doing the `a--` step. If you enter 0, `a` will be -1 at the time of that check. If you enter 1, `a` will be 0 at the time of that check. Both meet with the condition `a < 1`. Entering any other positive number won't pass the check.

Comment: I was trying different ways I can solve this problem (of printing first_name and last_name of 0 or 1 respectively).

Comment: What do you really want to do with this information?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the for loop is written with no initialization, condition, or increment expression (for (;;)). This creates an infinite loop that will continue running until explicitly terminated from inside the loop body.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("ENTER 0 or 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
      
        if (a == 0) {  
            printf("First_Name\n");  
        } 
        else if (a == 1) {  
            printf("Last_Name\n");  
        } 
        else {  
            printf("Wrong Input. Please Try Again.\n");
            continue; // Skip the rest of the loop body and start from the beginning
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can try this too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    
    while (1) {
        printf("ENTER 0 or 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
      
        if (a == 0) {  
            printf("First_Name\n");  
        } 
        else if (a == 1) {  
            printf("Last_Name\n");  
        } 
        else {  
            printf("Wrong Input. Please Try Again.\n");
            continue; 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can use this code to exit after 0 or 1. Loop only work when enter another number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    
    for (;;) { // Infinite loop
        printf("ENTER 0 or 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
      
        if (a == 0) {  
            printf("First_Name\n");  
            break; // Exit the loop
        } 
        else if (a == 1) {  
            printf("Last_Name\n");  
            break; // Exit the loop
        } 
        else {  
            printf("Wrong Input. Please Try Again.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you input  a negative number it keeps running the loop i believe it's because of the condition a < 1 if you input 2 for example it will break out of the loop.